# Many exceptions with javax.swing.plaf

Tags: java, swing

I use com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities for my swing application to give some fancy look for JFrame. My JRE is 1.6_29 .I use Netbeans IDE 7.0.1 . my swing application  gives various type of exceptions time to time as below

- `java.lang.ClassCastException:
  com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.DerivedColor$UIResource cannot be cast
  to java.awt.Insets`
- `java.lang.ClassCastException:

  com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.DerivedColor$UIResource cannot be cast
  to javax.swing.InputMap`
- `java.lang.ClassCastException:

  com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.DerivedColor$UIResource cannot be cast
  to java.lang.Boolean`
  all these exceptions do not come together. each one comes various times. But some time no exception at all, runs well.but sometimes those exceptions are thrown & then app doesn't work properly. Also I found that, if I do some change to the app (example: add new library then clean & build)then it works well. but the second time it runs, exceptions are thrown(one of above exceptions).Also I changed the themes,but it didn't solve.  Please any one let me know where my fault is in or how can I solve this please?

Comment: Do you run it within the IDE, or outside?

Comment: See also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: @Crollster, Thanks, with and wouthout IDE I ran the app. Same thing happened.